# What PRAGMA statements would be used inside an EXCEPTION block?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I was playing around with Oracle exceptions and tried to do some preprocessing between `EXCEPTION` and the `WHERE` statements. That is,

```
EXCEPTION
    some_operation_here();
    WHEN yaddayadda THEN
...
```

PL/SQL Developer said that that wasn't kosher – oh well – but its error message intrigued me: it was expecting either `WHEN` or `PRAGMA`. I am not thoroughly familiar with all the `PRAGMA` directives, but it doesn't seem like any of them are applicable in an exception block unless for some reason you waited till this point to bind an error code to an exception you had declared earlier. Why would you ever need to use a `PRAGMA` directive here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little experimentation tells me that you can, in fact put a `PRAGMA` in the exception block, but I can't see much use to it. The following executes successfully, but the raised error triggers the `OTHER` section, not the section for the newly defined exception (e.g. it returns "Old exception"). It would appear that this is an undocumented feature.

```
DECLARE
   v NUMBER;
   new_divide_zero EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   v := 1 / 0;
EXCEPTION
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (new_divide_zero, -1476);
   WHEN new_divide_zero THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('New exception');
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Old exception');
END;
```

---

Similarly, I tried putting a `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` in the exception block, but it too appears to have no effect (in this case, both rows are inserted).

```
CREATE TABLE test_results (result VARCHAR2 (2000));

BEGIN
   DECLARE
      v NUMBER;
      new_divide_zero EXCEPTION;
   BEGIN
      insert into test_results values ('Test Value');
      v := 1 / 0;
   EXCEPTION
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         INSERT INTO test_results
         VALUES      ('Old exception');
         Commit;
   END;
   ROLLBACK;
END;
```

---

The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/exception_handler.htm#sthref1843) (12g, which is the version i tested this on) does not mention using `PRAGMA` in the exception block, so it's definitely undocumented. On the other hand, it doesn't seem to be much of a feature, as it doesn't appear to actually do anything...

> WHEN { exception_name [ OR exception_name ]... | OTHERS }   THEN
>   statement [ statement ]...

Comment: Mysterious! Maybe they were just leaving room in their compiler for the hypothetical notion that a future new pragma will be useful there. I'll accept this answer in a day or two if nobody has anything not along the lines of, "Huh, I don't know either."

Comment: I had a theory that this was syntax that was inherited from Ada, since that was the model for PL/SQL. However, I can't find any evidence that Ada allows a `pragma` in the exception block either.

Answer (score 0):

It is syntax error. To catch exception you must use following syntax:

```
declare
  yaddayadda exception;
begin
  ...
exception
  WHEN yaddayadda THEN
    some_operation_here();
end;
```

You need to use `pragma exception_Init` to assign you custom exception with sql error code.
For example:

```
declre
  l_id number;
  e_resource_busy        EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_resource_busy, -54);
begin
   select id
     into l_id
     from job_table
    where status = 'RUNNING'
      for update nowait;
exception
  WHEN e_resource_busy THEN
     -- row is locked
    some_operation_here();
end;
```